# Getting warning for a Angularjs based project

Tags: angularjs

I am getting warning and i have reinstalled the visual studio 13 and Ctp 3.5 but still warning is there

> Warning    1   The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets

i have added the type script file after that  warning is not there but project is not building can any one help please.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I am using apache cordova for creating mobile application that is based on angularjs i have just deleted the cordova storage after that i am getting this warning Type script compiler was given no files for compilation so it will skip compiling because of this warning project is not building.